# How to sort an attribute inside a substring?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Lets assume that i have a table like this(3 columns)

```
date       number  year
3/1/2015   14      2015
1/1/2015   17      2015
2/1/2015   15      2015
1/1/2015   11      2015
```

I want a query something like :

```
select date,
       number||,'-'||year
order by date
```

But in the concatenation I want the results order by number.

So the output will be something like that:

```
date       number_year
1/1/2015   11-2015
1/1/2015   17-2015
2/1/2015   15-2015
3/1/2015   14-2015
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: Can you add (4, 2, 2015) and (5, 101, 2015) to your sample data, and also adjust expected result? BTW; which datatypes for number and year?

Comment: order by number, year?

Comment: yes,order by these two columns

Comment: The expected result will be (1,11,2015)(1,17,2015)(2,15,2015)(3,14,2015)(4,1,2015)(5,123,2015).The problem is when the id is the same

Comment: Did you try "order by number, year"?

Comment: Yes,i have tried,did not work

Comment: Your expected output in your question is **not** sorted by number

Comment: Was this ever figured out?  If so, please post the solution.  If not, please clarify with updated before/after example data as your examples and replies in comments don't seem to match.

Comment: Finally ,order by number solve my problem,thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple conditions in your order by clause, please refer to oracle documentation :
http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.2.2/ref/rrefsqlj13658.html

So you could definitely have order by id, number, year
for instance